# Pop up image onclick covering whole site

Tags: javascript, image, background, onclick, cover

I need to pop up a whole background on click.
It could be done something like an image on the center of page making a whole website less visible and changing after few secs to other image or covering whole web page with my image transforming after few second to next whole web page image. After click everything back to normal.

```
<div id="right_center"><img style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='knee_fun()' id="iImg" src="img/knee.png" ></div>


<script>
var time = 3000;
var picNo = 0;
var pics = new Array
(
'img/urazy_1.png',
'img/urazy_2.png',
'img/empty.png'
);

function knee_fun()
{

document.getElementById('iImg').src = pics[picNo++];
if (picNo >1 ) picNo =2; 


setTimeout('knee_fun()', time);
clearTimeout('knee_fun()');

}
</script>
```

I made this= cycling 2 images but how to position it on the center of the page and not reorganizing whole page? I need also to make less visible all the page content during this images cycle. (it should end after click).
Other option is to make a images cycle which contains full page but it need to cover whole web page. and after click back to normal.

ow in addition how to add second function with parametr?

```
            <div id="zoom" onClick="document.getElementById('song').play()">
            <audio id="song" src="nanana.mp3"></audio>
            </div>
```

when i add: onclick="doc~(); injuries_change();" id="iImg"> second isnt working

Comment: Are you trying to show full page image slider..? @KrzysztofWielgat

Comment: Not exactly. I have edited my post. I need to position an images cycle on the center of the page and not reorganizing whole page. I need also to make less visible all the page content during this images cycle. (it should end after click). Just image cycle without any border or quitting mark. Just quit after click.